# ESLint no restricted globals with Object.values in TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, eslint

I am getting an ESLint error for `no restricted globals`:

```
const objectParamsAllNumbers = (obj: Object) =>
  !Object.values(obj).find(elem => {
    return isNaN(elem);
  });
```

I tried adding `ES2017.Object` to my `tsconfig` but the error is still throwing:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": true,  // Warn you if you write certain code that can’t be correctly interpreted by a single-file transpilation process.
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["ESNEXT", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES5", "ES2017", "ES2017.Object"],
    "allowJs": true, // Allow JavaScript files to be imported inside your project, instead of just .ts and .tsx
    "checkJs": true,  // When checkJs is enabled then errors are reported in JavaScript files. This is the equivalent of including // @ts-check at the top of all JavaScript files which are included in your project.
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // Allow default imports from modules with no default export
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["node", "webpack-env", "@wdio/sync", "mocha", "expect-webdriverio"],
    "strict": false // Enables all strict type checking options (This is too restrictive for the current code base)
  },
```

Comment: If the error is for the `no-restricted-globals` rule, I wouldn't expect it to relate to `lib`. But there aren't any restricted globals in your code. Can you give a bit more context and copy and paste the **exact** error you get and any context it provides?

Comment: I'd guess that `isNan` is the "restricted global" in this case (because it doesn't behave the way most people expect) - but we need to see what's in your eslint config. (See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing it on the window object like `window.Object`.

```
const objectParamsAllNumbers = (obj: Object) =>
  !window.Object.values(obj).find(elem => {
    return window.isNaN(elem);
});
```